# Change the value of select dropdown when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have to do a event when checkbox is unchecked then select dropdown value is set to be null or default.

**Html code:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_8am_10am" id="tomorrow_8am_10am" value="8am-10am">8am - 10am</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_8am_10am box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_8am_10am">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_10am_12pm" id="tomorrow_10am_12pm" value="10am-12pm">10am - 12pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_10am_12pm box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_10am_12pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox ">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" id="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" value="12pm-2pm">12pm - 2pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_12pm_2pm box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_12pm_2pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
```

In above code i am append/show dropdown on click of checkbox.
Now i have to do this when i uncheck the checkbox at that time set the value of dropdown to be null/default.

**Javascript code:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("id");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle();
});
```

This is my JS code, from this i am appending the select div beside my checkbox.

Can anyone help me for that?

Comment: Can you post you JavaScript / jQuery that you're using to append / show the dropdown on click as well please?

Comment: @ObsidianAge - yes, i edit my question. Now you can see it.

Comment: @Darshan  do you want to set select box to 'No Preference' when u change the checkbox state or u want to add and select a new option with empty value?

Comment: @ajaiJothi - yes i have to set select box to 'No Preference' when i change the checkbox state.

Comment: After your toggle code add the following condtion `if(!$(this).is(':checked)){ $("." + inputValue).find('select').val("-1");` }

Answer (score 2):

Try this! :D

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('click change',function() {
        $(this).closest('div.checkbox').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',$(this).val()>0);
    });
    $('input:checkbox').on('click change',function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) $(this).closest('div.checkbox').find('select').val('-1');
    });
});
```

See working demo on codeply:
http://www.codeply.com/go/7t3ZvFz5yF

Answer (score 2):

### Do something when checkbox is unchecked

Inside of your function, you can check whether the checkbox is checked/unchecked with:

```
if (this.checked)
```

or

```
if (!this.checked)
```

and put whatever code you want to execute based on this condition in the `if` block.

### Select an option from dropdown with jQuery

You can use the value attribute of the option you want to select:

```
$('#yourDropdown select').val('valueOfOptionToBeSelected`);
```

### Example:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("id");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    
    if (!this.checked) {
      
      $("." + inputValue + ' select').val('-1');
    
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_8am_10am" id="tomorrow_8am_10am" value="8am-10am">8am - 10am</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_8am_10am box" style="display:none">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_8am_10am">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_10am_12pm" id="tomorrow_10am_12pm" value="10am-12pm">10am - 12pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_10am_12pm box" style="display:none">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_10am_12pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox ">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" id="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" value="12pm-2pm">12pm - 2pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_12pm_2pm box" style="display:none">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_12pm_2pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
```

Also, I'm not sure what your intention is, but you might want to add `display: none` to hide the drop down on page load, and then toggle the visibility when the user interacts with the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I get what you want.  When you check a box, it selects 1 (or whatever you would prefer).  When you uncheck, it sets it back to no preference.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $("." + inputValue + " select").val(1);
 } else {
  $("." + inputValue + " select").val(-1);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_8am_10am" id="tomorrow_8am_10am" value="8am-10am">8am - 10am</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_8am_10am box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_8am_10am">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_10am_12pm" id="tomorrow_10am_12pm" value="10am-12pm">10am - 12pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_10am_12pm box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_10am_12pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox ">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" id="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" value="12pm-2pm">12pm - 2pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_12pm_2pm box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_12pm_2pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.tomorrow-schedule-time').is(':checked')){
            //
            } else {

               $('select').append('<option>Default</option>');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    var $select = $(this).parents('.checkbox').find('select');
    console.log($select.length);
    $select.val("1");
    
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('uncheck');
      $select.val("-1");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_8am_10am" id="tomorrow_8am_10am" value="8am-10am">8am - 10am</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_8am_10am box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_8am_10am">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_10am_12pm" id="tomorrow_10am_12pm" value="10am-12pm">10am - 12pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_10am_12pm box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_10am_12pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
<div class="checkbox ">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tomorrow-schedule-time" name="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" id="tomorrow_12pm_2pm" value="12pm-2pm">12pm - 2pm</label>
    <i class="tomorrow_12pm_2pm box">
        <select name="pref_tomorrow_12pm_2pm">
            <option value="-1">No Preferences</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </i>
</div>
```